# Copy rows from one sheet into another depending on value in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in my spreadsheet and I'm looking for some VBA code (or a simple formula) to batch copy values from one sheet into the other.

Sheet1, has a list of cities, markets and products in three columns (A-C). Close to 19,000 rows in total.
[image]

Sheet2, has a list of products, product sub-category, and product origin (columns A-C), Close to 300 rows in total.
[image]

I would like to copy product sub-category and product origin (i.e. columns B and C in Sheet2) into Sheet1 where Product in Column C of Sheet1 = Product in Column A of Sheet2. Noting that I would like to keep the order that the rows are in Sheet2 when copying to Sheet1.

I tried the following INDEX/MATCH approach, but it stops working after the 18th row (I have close to 19,000 rows in Sheet1), and it only works for one column at a time.

> =IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$284, SMALL(IF($D2='Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$284, ROW('Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$284)-1,""), ROW()-1)),"")

Example output using the sample data:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of the desired output? It's unclear to me how the multiple occurences of a product in `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are supposed to be matched. Does the pattern in `Sheet1` differ from what you showed us? If it's a repeating pattern you could simply copy the data in `Sheet2` by hand, that would be the quickest way.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. I've added an example output in the edit above. I was trying to avoid copying manually as the data in Sheet1 is 19,000 rows long. If it helps, there are 11 types of product in total, which recur over multiple rows in Sheet1, but not in the same order as in Sheet2. However, when copying over from Sheet2 into Sheet1, I would like to keep the same order of Product - Product sub-category - Product origin that is in Sheet2. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

if it is just copying static data repeatedly then perhaps something like this. If not, then i misunderstood your question.
this is the formula in cell B2:

```
=INDEX(Copy.Table,IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$1),Table.Count)=0,$E$2,MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$1),Table.Count)))
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously in your solution, you would need two "Copy.Table" (i.e. the yellow table) one for the product sub-category and one for the product origin

Comment: Hi, thank you, I'm afraid I'm a bit unclear on how to use your formula. How would it work with eleven different products that each recur a different number of times in Sheet1 and Sheet2? E.g. 'Cheese' recurs 5 times (i.e. five different combinations of Product-Product sub-category-Product origin), but 'Nuts' recurs 37 times?

Comment: i don't know how your data is structured. If all cities and all markets have the same products then you can adapt my formula. if that's not the case then you can't use it.